# Disproving the mathematical universe hypothesis

Tags: cosmology, soft-question, mathematics

The mathematical universe hypothesis is [claimed](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2013/07/ideas-bank/why-the-universe-just-doesnt-add-up) by Lee Smolin to be falsifiable:

> *[...] it is easy to disprove the mathematical-universe hypothesis. Simply exhibit one property of the natural world that is not shared by any mathematical object.*

Are there observed properties that are not mathematical?

Comment: There are no paradoxes in special relativity. And the uncertainty principle has a firm mathematical basis (it's a property of Fourier transforms). Personally, the Mathematical Universe strikes me as an *un*falsifiable and possibly even tautological hypothesis when you consider what mathematics actually is.

Comment: To expand on @lemon, mathematics is the study of rules and how rules can form a system of rules. There are branches of mathematics that don't deal with numbers at all. So, like science and physics, anything that isn't yet described by mathematics can be studied and described by mathematics.

Comment: Define "mathematical property".

Comment: What counts as a property of the natural world? And what does it mean for the world to share that property with a mathematical object?

Comment: Too bad... I thought Smolin was smarter than that. Physics has a very clean ontology in that every theoretical quantity has to be expressed in some form of approximated physical measurement device. This automatically excludes testability for infinitesimal deformations, which are clearly "mathematical" in nature.

Comment: "Simply exhibit one property of the natural world that is not shared by any mathematical object". Easy: the world is our home.

Answer (score 5):

A very weakly argued article that seems unworthy of Smolin. It finally degenerates into magical/emotional/wishful thinking.

> A non-mathematical universe evolving today is also more conducive to
>   human aspirations. As there is no timeless mathematical object that
>   captures all the truth about the world, the future need not be
>   determined. Humans have evolved the organ of imagination that makes
>   the invention of novelty as effortless as play. So human will and
>   agency are not illusions -- they can be as real as atoms. We are free
>   to believe in our innate human capacity to invent novel solutions to
>   our most pressing problems.

In the end, he does not provide any example of an object that cannot be described mathematically. It's as embarrassing as an appeal to "God" or "Life Force" in a science article.

Comment: whats embarrassing about God?

Comment: @good_ole_ray The fact is that the concept of "God" (ignoring the fact that there are hundreds/thousands of them) is that it offers no useful information concerning any problem, nor any explanations more usable than "it is this way because it is". A redundant concept/tool in science.

Comment: how about the problem of intelligent design in biological systems, fine tuning of the universe, human free will, origin of universe, and many others.. which cannot be explained by materialistic , naturalistic theories.

Comment: @good_ole_ray - OK - "God did it". Now what?

Comment: now a little respect. not "it's as embarassing as an appeal to God"...

Comment: @good_ole_ray OK - "It's as useless as an appeal to the notion of "God"". Although don't you find (as I do) that an appeal to a useless notion which leads nowhere in what should be a scientific article somewhat embarrassing?

Comment: you're right in a scientific article it is not along the standard methods of science. just i wouldnt call it embarassing for respect purposes. btw, dont think its useless notion. as we go on, it is becoming more obvious that an intelligence is involved see the end of http://successfulstudent.org/dr-michael-denton-interview/

Answer (score 1):

If there was an observed property which was 'not mathematical' then, in order to be able to do science, you need to be able to describe how to observe this property.  You'd want to be able to do this in some way which, for instance, would allow other people to repeat your observation: in a formal language, say.  Such a language is mathematical, and so the property is now described by some mathematics, and so fails to be non-mathematical.

This leaves only properties which *have no formal description*.  Such properties are not amenable to falsification.

---

Someone is going to raise Gödel's theorems at this point.  I don't think this is relevant.  Even if it was, the theorems talk about the undecidability of statements in *fixed* systems of axioms: you can always throw in new axioms for any *given* statement of interest.  However I think that it's still just not relevant to physics.

---

This whole question probably belongs in some philosophy stack exchange however.

Comment: disagree that only mathematical properties have formal description

Comment: @good_ole_ray: and that's why this belongs in some philosophy forum.

Comment: except that i am asking on physical properties

Comment: @good_ole_ray: yes, but if properties described in a formal language are not mathematical the question becomes about what maths is and that's not a question about physics.